# How many spells does a level 3 Tiefling Warlock have?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

Tried reading through the PHB, and every post here, but no luck!

I'm a level 3 Tiefling Warlock and so:

1. Infernal Legacy says I know the Thaumaturgy cantrip.
2. My Otherworldly Patron is Fiend and "the following spells are added to the warlock spell list". Spell Level 1: burning hands, command. Spell Level 2: blindness/deafness, scorching ray.
3. I have two eldritch invocations: I chose agonizing blast and fiendish vigor.
4. My Pact Boon is Pact of the Tome; allowing me to choose three cantrips. (This explanation was pretty clear at least).

So here are my questions!

1. How many cantrips and spells do I know? My assumption is 6 cantrips and 4 spells.
2. Other than cantrips, how many spells can I cast? I assume three: using the two spell slots as per the table on page 106 of the PHB *plus* False Life via Fiendish Vigor.

Is this correct?

Comment: I was about to submit an answer when it donned on me... *do the spells mentioned by the invocations such as Fiendish Vigor count against your Spells Known?* I didn't think they would at first, but I counted at least 12 Invocations like Fiendish Vigor that dont have prerequisites other than a level requirement. You know 15 spells at max and 8 invocations, yet you can only cast 4 spells. It would make sense that you would use those invocations to maximize spell utility if the spells they mention do in fact count against spells known and aren't *extras* like i first assumed... now i am confused.

Comment: To add to my own confusion, I just noticed on p 43 of he PHB that, as a lvl 3 Tiefling, I can ALSO cast Hellish Rebuke, which I assume means the answer to both questions increases by one, no?

Comment: The racial stuff is most definitely extras on top of the class abilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For your specific character, you are correct.**

However you left off the invocations (which can be quite invaluable and often act as a spell without needing a spell slot). I'll break this down specific to your character:

**Cantrips:** 2 base +3 from Pact of the Tome = 5 cantrips (+1 from Infernal Legacy covered below)

**Spells:** 4 known + Hellish Rebuke - these spells must be selected from the Warlock spell list. The Great Old one patron allows you to select from an *expanded* spell list which includes the spells listed under Great Old One on PHB pg. 110. This means you can select from these spells when you learn a new spell, not that you know them in addition to the ones you do select.

**Invocations:** 2 invocations, these do not count against spells known. There is no requirement to know the spell in advance, otherwise this would be addressed under prerequisites in the invocation. In fact, the Invocations have a different name, and you can infer that the name of the Invocation is the Warlock version of said spell, with the spell name under said Invocation being used as reference to it's capability. This is demonstrated through Invocations such as Armor of Shadows which is effectively Mage Armor without the spell slot or material component requirement. Another example is Book of Ancient Secrets, which besides letting you pick any 2 rituals from any class (wow!), it allows you to cast a lot of your Warlock spells as rituals so you don't have to expend a spell slot (which are invaluable as a Warlock).

**Infernal Legacy:** All spells known from this are separate and distinct from your spell slots and invocations. These do not use spell slots to cast but function on a specific recharge as indicated by the description under Infernal Legacy. This is separate and distinct because it is not a Warlock feature, but a Race feature and does not require spellcasting or pact magic in order to utilize (it's in effect the same thing as a Dragonborn breath weapon).