# Does "Spare the Dying" eat up a Warlock cantrip slot?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

The Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide, for the Undying Otherworldly (Warlock) Patron, on page 139 explicitly says

> Starting at 1st level, you learn the Spare the Dying cantrip, which counts as a Warlock cantrip for you.

Does that mean you're now forced to take this cantrip and use up one of your cantrip "slots", or does it mean you now have access to learn it if you choose to?

Does it actually mean that you get Spare the Dying *in addition* to the 2 cantrips you already get?

> counts as a warlock cantrip for you

could be read with the context: "as opposed to counting as a Cleric cantrip"... so that's why I'm finding it confusing.

Comment: [Related] [Do cantrips granted by Magic Initiate count towards "Cantrips Known"?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69268) • [How many spells does a level 3 Tiefling Warlock have?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67925)

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour].  There are guidelines on how to ask a good question.   As a Q and A site, the better the question, the better the answers.  The edit I have provided adds necessary detail to your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you just get a free Cantrip. For reference, look at the High Elf from the PHB (24), where

> "You know one cantrip of your choice from the wizard spell list. Intelligence is your spell casting ability for it.

Or, the Cleric Light domain, where you gain the 'light' cantrip if you don't already know it.

The additional qualifiers simply clarify that the spell is treated as being on the warlock spell list for you, much like the spells from your patron are treated as warlock spells for you. At the least, that qualifier allows you to use magic items or scrolls that have the effect as well. Without that qualifier, features and traits that apply to your warlock spells would not apply to such cantrips/spells.

Comment: I'm not sure how examples of other cantrips are answering the question, and your final paragraph appears to be incomplete. And also wrong, since patron spells still need to be chosen as known spells before you can use them.

Comment: @Miniman - Precisely; the spells made available to you through your patron are considered to be on the warlock spell lists. Edited for comprehension.

Comment: @Miniman - As to the referencing other cantrips, those are a few incidents from the PHB where a player can have more cantrips than detailed by the class tables.

Comment: Obviously - but you don't draw that comparison in your answer. You just say "For reference" and throw them out there as if they answer the question just by existing. And your last paragraph is still incomplete - I'm guessing you meant to say that "The additional qualifiers [...] ***are*** much like the spells from your patron [...]".

Answer (score 11):

It is in addition to your regular cantrips known. Your regular cantrips would be chosen in the character creation process before adding this feature due to the order of listing of class features.

Answer (score 1):

### Warlock's do not have a limit on cantrips known

The Warlock's *Pact Magic* feature [states](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#ClassFeatures):

> **Cantrips**
> You know two cantrips of your choice from the warlock spell list. You learn additional warlock cantrips of your choice at higher levels, as shown in the Cantrips Known column of the Warlock table.

The Cantrips Known section of the Warlock table only tells you how many cantrips you learn from the *Pact Magic* feature. It has no relevance to cantrips learned through other features including sub-class features such as the Undying's *Among the Dead*.